# Synchronise data between Desktop and app (best practise)

Tags: mysql, firebase, websocket, real-time, nativescript

I have a website which uses Mysql database. Now I am developing a nativescript app. I was wondering what are the options to synchronise data between desktop and app. For example, if somebody comments on the post, the comment should appear on the app without reloading it. After some research I found Firebase real time database, the problem is the I would have to duplicate and synchronise Mysql and firebase databases. another options in my mind is use to websockets. Could anybody advise what are other options and what are the best practise? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could use firebase all the way and drop the mysql DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally this should have been thought through and planned at the initial system design & architecture stage and should have planned Firebase or such cloud database service which could have helped in implementing realtime updates between different connected clients/nodes.

At this stage it would be better if you implement WebSockets to send data for realtime updates to connected clients.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, that exactly what I am going to do. I didn't see the big picture of this project at the beginning.